# Why is this MySQL insert query not working?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, debugging

I have the following MySQL query which I am trying to execute in ASP.NET:

```
INSERT INTO LUIPPS (IPPID, IPPNAME, IPPEMAIL) VALUES ('2', 'AC DC', 'num@ghi.com.pk,aaz@abc.com.pk,asd@def.com.pk')
```

I am using `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` library.

I am getting the following exception while using the `ExecuteNonQuery` function:

```
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?INSERT INTO LUIPPS (IPPID, IPPNAME, IPPEMAIL) VALUES (2, 'AC DC', 'num@' at line 1"
```

Debug console shows: `Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll`

It's a syntactic error but I can't seem to find it. I have done the debugging as well where I have checked the value of *str* (which contains the query) in MySqlCommand object.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, CON);
```

Its character to character the same as specified above. In fact, I have copied it from hovering over `str` while debugging.

I have checked the DB as well which seems fine. The following image is the screenshot of the DB:

[image]

Kindly guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to run the same query directly from Work Bench?

Comment: try enclosing table and column name with backtick character.
INSERT INTO 'LUIPPS' ('IPPID', 'IPPNAME', 'IPPEMAIL') VALUES ....

Comment: Why is there a question mark before INSERT?

Comment: @OwenPauling I don't know where it came from in the exception message. In the value of 'str' (which contains the query), there is no question mark.

Comment: @A_Name_Does_Not_Matter that worked!!! But I have multiple other queries where I haven't used the backtick character and they work just fine.

Comment: Can you show your code?